# F# return list of list lengths

Tags: list, f#, combinators

I am to use combinators and no  for/while loops, recursion or defined library functions from F#'s List module, except constructors :: and []

Ideally I want to implement map

I am trying to write a function called llength that returns the list of the lengths of the sublists. For example llength [[1;2;3];[1;2];[1;2;3]] should return [3;2,3]. I also have function length that returns the length of a list.

```
let Tuple f = fun a b -> f (a, b)
let length l : int =
    List.fold (Tuple (fst >> (+) 1)) 0 l
```

currently have

```
let llength l : int list =
    List.map (length inner list) list
```

Not sure how I should try accessing my sublists with my restraints and should I use my other method on each sublist? any help is greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Have you noticed that you're using `List.fold`? Isn't that against the rules? Also: is this homework? If so, please tag it as such.

Comment: its not allowing me to add that tag, and there was some included combinator methods we were allowed, such as even, all, fold, filter

Answer (score 6):

Since this is homework, I don't want to just give you a fully coded solution, but here are some hints:

**First**, since `fold` is allowed you could implement `map` via `fold`. The folding function would take the list accumulated "so far" and prepend the next element transformed with mapping function. The result will come out reversed though (`fold` traverses forward, but you prepend at every step), so perhaps that wouldn't work for you if you're not allowed `List.rev`.

**Second** - the most obvious, fundamental way: naked recursion. Here's the way to think about it: (1) when the argument is an empty list, result should be an empty list; (2) when the argument is a non-empty list, the result should be length of the argument's head prepended to the list of lengths of the argument's tail, which can be calculated recursively. Try to write that down in F#, and there will be your solution.

Comment: Oh, I misread about recursion, sorry. Well, I'm afraid you either need `fold` + `rev`, or `fold` + `append`, or `map`, or recursion. No way around it.

Comment: I would like to try using map

Comment: Would like to use map, I edited my post. Am I on the right track

Answer (score 0):

Since you can use some functions that basically have a loop (`fold`, `filter` ...), there might be some "cheated & dirty" ways to implement `map`. For example, via `filter`:

```
let mymap f xs =
    let mutable result = []
    xs
    |> List.filter (fun x ->
        result <- f x :: result
        true)
    |> ignore
    result |> List.rev
```

Note that `List.rev` is required as explained in the other answer.